# How do I make this ASP.NET vb Login and Password also redirect to different pages?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url, authentication, passwords

I have the following code:

```
Private ReadOnly _credentials = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
  {"userone", "passwordone"},
  {"usertwo", "passwordtwo"},
  {"userthree", "passwordthree"}
}

Public Sub Login(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim storedPassword = ""
    If _credentials.TryGetValue(UserName.Text, storedPassword) And storedPassword = Password.Text Then
    Session("Admin") = True
    Response.Redirect("/admin/default.aspx")
End If

    Session("Admin") = False
    LtlLogin.Text = "<p>Sorry you have provided incorrect login details.</p>"
End Sub
```

The above code works beautifully, but how can I make it so each user is then (providing Login and Password OK) directed to a different URL in the 'protected' area?

I also have this code on all the 'protected area' pages:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs)
 If Session("Admin") <> True Then
  Response.Redirect("/admin/access.aspx")
 End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for super simple (which it looks like you are given you're storing credentials in the form), you could just modify your data store:

```
Public Class MyPage
    Inherits Page

    ' Assumed web controls present
    'Private UserName As WebControls.TextBox
    'Private Password As WebControls.TextBox
    'Private LtlLogin as WebControls.Label

    ' Create a simple structure so we can store username,
    ' password and (optionally) a page to be passed off to
    ' once logged in
    Private Structure Cred
        Public Username As String
        Public Password As String
        Public RedirectUrl As String
        Public Sub New(un As String, pw As String, Optional ru As String = "/admin/default.aspx")
            Username = un
            Password = pw
            RedirectUrl = ru
        End Sub
    End Structure

    Private ReadOnly _credentials As IEnumerable(Of Cred) = New Cred() { _
        ' Current credentials
        New Cred("userone", "passwordone"), _
        New Cred("usertwo", "passwordtwo"), _
        New Cred("userthree", "passwordthree", "/admin/custom.aspx") _
    }

    Public Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' See if we have a credential match
        Dim user = _credentials.SingleOrDefault(Function(x) x.Username = UserName.Text AndAlso x.Password = Password.Text)
        If Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Username) Then
            ' Match found, log them in and redirect
            Session("Admin") = True
            Response.Redirect(user.RedirectUrl)
        Else
            ' No match found, deny access and notify
            Session("Admin") = False
            LtlLogin.Text = "<p>Sorry, you have provided incorrect login details.</p>"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Basically, instead of storing information as tuples (or dictionary key/values), use a struct to associate a redirectUrl to each username.

Comment: Thanks Brad. However I get: BC32045: 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments. Any ideas why? Cheers!

Comment: @d.c: Give that a shot. I apoligize, VB is not my first (preferred) language, so some of the nomenclature tends to be off. ;-)